# How to show button following the value of an input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a button when the value of the input text set by the user is the same as the value of my hidden input text, already is the same value after consulting console.
When I try it I put the right value in my text input and it's not working

```js
document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
function action() {
  document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   var x = document.getElementById('numexam').value;
   var z =  document.getElementById('numexam2').value;
   if(x==z) {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'visible';
   } else {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
}
```

```html
<form action="/demandeverification" method="post" >
    <input required type="text"  onChange="action()"id="numexam"/>
    <input   type="hidden" id="numexam2" />
    <button  id="btn" type="submit" />Envoyer demande</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any value set to your hidden input element to compare with the other input element's value. I set that to `xyz` for demonstration purpose. Also you should not name your function as `action` which leads to an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: action is not a function

```js
document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
function myAction() {
  document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   var x = document.getElementById('numexam').value;
   var z =  document.getElementById('numexam2').value;
   if(x==z) {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'visible';
   } else {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
}
```

```html
<form action="/demandeverification" method="post" >
  <input required type="text"  onchange="myAction()" id="numexam"/>
  <input   type="hidden" value="xyz" id="numexam2" />
  <button  id="btn" type="submit" />Envoyer demande</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's getting the value from a button using onClick="document.getElementById('numexam2').innerHTML=this.value" value="{{$exam->num}}" 
 and when i use console i can see the value their

Comment: @MehdiElAissi, `onClick="document.getElementById('numexam2').innerHTML=this.value" value="{{$exam->num}}` this is not valid code in JS..

Answer (score 0):

Use style display `block` and `none` respectively. Try:

```
...
 if(x==z) {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.display= 'block';
   } else {
    document.getElementById('btn').style.display= 'none';
   }
```

Comment: It's not working but when I have used browser console it's showing me an error 
Uncaught TypeError: action is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Answer (score 0):

You need to change function name and it's work properly.

```
<form action="/demandeverification" method="post" >
<input required type="text"  onChange="action1()" id="numexam"/>
<input type="hidden" id="numexam2" />
<button id="btn" type="submit" />Envoyer demande</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
function action1() {

    document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    var x = document.getElementById('numexam').value;
    var z = document.getElementById('numexam2').value;
    if (x == z) {
        document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('btn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
</script>
```